# Problem in manuscript (.tex) submission in elsevier

Tags: journal

My manuscript was prepared using TexWorks, usingthe elsarticle template from Elsevier website link. Everything works and compiled to pdf properly in TexWorks.
The problem occurs when I tried submission of manuscript. It did not compile.

To reduce the possibility of bibtex problem, I used bibitem in my manuscript.tex. Still, it did not work in elsevier manuscript submission.
How do I trace the problem given the uncompiled file as attached? Please give me some suggestion and tips to solve this. Thank you.

Some questions:
1. Does the sequence order file matters?
2. manuscript.tex.. should be labelled as *Manuscript or Latex Source Files
3. What are the common files to be uploaded?

The full uncompile file can be obtained via link as follows.
[my uncompile file for reference](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1S_IS47tkS7n8NBB1slGBc90rGnImF71v/view?usp=sharing)

[image: screenshot of uncompile file]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please don't include file by links!

Comment: What error do you get? Have you a log-file of the failed compilation?

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer: In my TexWorks, it did not fail. It fails during submission online. I did not get log file from the journal.

Comment: Well without some data about the error it is impossible to say why it fails. Ask the journal. Your log-file do show errors, as it shows a compilation to dvi but tries to include png.

Answer (score 4):

Problem was solved.

For the record, this is the problem I faced when submit manuscript to Elsevier CAP.

1. The figures should be put under "Manuscript". In my case, .png did not work, so, I changed to .pdf for figures and problem solved.
2. I did not included zipped source file, it is still ok.
3. .cls file also should be uploaded as "Manuscript".
4. The order doesn't affect anything.
5. Using bibitem only directly in .tex works OK
6. Option to use BibTex with .bst and .bib files, also works now:)

[image: screenshot of my uploaded files]

[image]

Comment: additional reference:http://www.bartneck.de/2010/09/30/submitting-your-latex-manuscript-to-editorial-manager-springer-elsevier/

Comment: I am still facing the problem. The file compiles if the documentclass is article. With documentclass is elsarticle, the file doesn't compile.

Comment: Thanks! I tried many things so far but finally this post saved me! This answer is really important since marking everything as manuscript sounds really counter-intuitive.

Comment: This. Exactly this. This user-interface is so unintuitive. Who, in their right mind thinks it is a good idea to offer a "Latex Source File" category as an option, when it is actually "Manuscript" that EVERTHING needs to be submitted as.
  
Thank you for saving me from wasting even more precious hours of my life with this atrocious submission system.
  
Ye who submit there, abandon all hope.